# Flutter SDK Problem After Updating The Windows

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

After make update the windows I got the below errors and I don't know why this happen.

> D:/dev/courses/flutter/flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/stacked_services-0.4.11/lib/src/snackbar_service.dart:74:7:
> Error: Type 'SnackStatusCallback' not found.
> SnackStatusCallback onStatusChanged,
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /D:/dev/courses/flutter/flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/stacked_services-0.4.11/lib/src/navigation_service.dart:94:35:
> Error: The getter 'defaultDurationTransition' isn't defined for the
> class '_GetImpl'.
>
> - '_GetImpl' is from 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart' ('/D:/dev/courses/flutter/flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-3.24.0/lib/get_core/src/get_main.dart').
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining
>   a getter or field named 'defaultDurationTransition'.
>   duration: duration ?? Get.defaultDurationTransition,
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /D:/dev/courses/flutter/flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/stacked_services-0.4.11/lib/src/navigation_service.dart:113:33:
>   Error: The getter 'defaultDurationTransition' isn't defined for the
>   class '_GetImpl'.
> - '_GetImpl' is from 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart' ('/D:/dev/courses/flutter/flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-3.24.0/lib/get_core/src/get_main.dart').
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining
>   a getter or field named 'defaultDurationTransition'.
>   duration: duration ?? Get.defaultDurationTransition,
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /D:/dev/courses/flutter/flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/stacked_services-0.4.11/lib/src/snackbar_service.dart:74:7:
>   Error: 'SnackStatusCallback' isn't a type.
>   SnackStatusCallback onStatusChanged,
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /D:/dev/courses/flutter/flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/stacked_services-0.4.11/lib/src/snackbar_service.dart:111:9:
>   Error: No named parameter with the name 'onStatusChanged'.
>   onStatusChanged: onStatusChanged,
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /D:/dev/courses/flutter/flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-3.24.0/lib/get_navigation/src/snackbar/snack.dart:12:3:
>   Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
>   GetBar({   ^^^^^^ 2
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Script 'D:\dev\courses\flutter\flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle'
>   line: 904

Comment: try to run flutter doctor to see if you have any problem, and then flutter clean and re-run your build

Comment: I tried this solution and nothing changed.